# Super Admin service account not finding resource calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-directory-api

I'm attempting to list all events from a Google Workspace Resource Calendar which results in either a "user not found" or "invalid impersonation" depending on which calendar identifier I use. The same code works for normal users but not specifically resource calendars.

```php
$client = new Client();
$client->setApplicationName($this->getName());
$client->setAuthConfig("{$this->configLocation}/{$this->keyReceiving}"); // Service Account JSON Key
$client->setSubject($resource->getResourceEmail()); // Conference room email address
$client->setScopes($this->scopes); // [Calendar::CALENDAR, Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS, Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_RESOURCE_CALENDAR]

$calendarService = new Calendar($client);
$events = $calendarService->events->listEvents("primary");
```

The difference between "normal users" and resources is that the domain for resources is `@resource.calendar.google.com` and users is `@domain.com` where the domain is my own. This results in a "User not found" error. Edit: All resources are owned by the same organization as my service account key and domain wide delegation is generated for.

If I instead change the subject to `$resource->getResourceID()` which is a numeric ID instead of an email address it results in a "Invalid impersonation" error.

If I use my own Super Admin account I can list any normal user calendar, but if I attempt to list a resource calendar either by `ID` or `Email` I get the error "404 Not Found" - as if the calendar object does not exist.

Is the above approach correct for listing (and later updating) a resource calendar events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears because the `setSubject()` method is using a Resource, this method is only used to [impersonate other users](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-server.md#preparing-to-make-an-authorized-api-call) in order to perform the API call on their behalf.

When using a resource calendar the code is telling Google *"I'm this conference room please get my `primary` calendar"*. You can try this instead:

```php
$client->setSubject($adminEmailAddress); // A Super admin email address

...

$events = $calendarService->events->listEvents($resource->getResourceEmail());
```